# is there any way to tackle if the value in one-pair of hashmap matches with the key in other pair?

Tags: java, hashmap

Iam sorry in advance as I really don't have way to express the problem i want to ask for, but here i could brief with the help of my example code that what i want

```
static { 
  hashmap.put("Bus","Land_Vehicle");
  hashmap.put("Land_Vehicle","Vehicle"); 
  hashmap.put("SchoolBus","Bus");
  hashmap.put("Truck","Land_Vehicle");
  } 
  public static void checkRelationship(String key, String value) { 

      String val1=hashmap.get(key);
      String val2=hashmap.get(value);

          if(hashmap.containsKey(key) && hashmap.get(key).equals(value)==true) {

              System.out.println("values: "+val1+val2);
              System.out.println(" Something is missing in-between");


          }
```

If I needs to check the Relationship for `("Bus", "Vehicle")` it should prompt a message that something is missing, as the Value for `"Bus"` and Key for the `"Vehicle"` are same i.e. `Land_Vehicle`.

Here i want to mentioned that `String val1`, `val2` store the values `"Land_Vehicle"` and `"Vehicle"` respectively when iam checking the relationship for `("Bus", "Land_Vehicle");` but i dont understand how to check the relationship for `("Bus", "Vehicle")`.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? And what are you expecting from `String val2=hashmap.get(value)`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, but If user wants to check the relationship for ("Bus", "Vehicle") it should prompt a message that "Something is missing in-between". String values are only used to test the middle values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the relationship between `Bus` and `Vehicle` try this:

```
public static void checkRelationship(String key, String value) {
    String val1=hashmap.get(key);  // get "Land_Vehicle"

    // get value by "Land_Vehicle" and compare with "Vehicle"
    if (value.equals(hashmap.get(val1))) {    
        System.out.println("Something is missing in-between");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alots, Life becomes easier because of peoples like you. Stay Blessed!